# PowerShell - Restructuring code to remove from group, then add to group before going to next group

Tags: powershell

You will have to forgive me as I am defiantly beyond my capabilities here.

I have 2 lists, both containing a Group and then Skills.  The first list are skills that need to be removed from the group, and the second is a list that have to be added back on.

| Group | Skill |
| --- | --- |
| Group1 | Skill1 |
| Group1 | Skill2 |
| Group2 | Skill1 |
| Group2 | Skill2 |
| ... | ... |
| Group15 | Skill7 |

I am able to do this by pulling the list in (its in CSV format) and removing all the skills from the groups, and then re-adding them all.

```
foreach ($groups in $Profiles2Cleanse) {
<command called that actually performs this on a platform but removed for privacy>
Write-Output "$(Get-Date) - Removing - $($groups.Group) - $($groups.Skill)" #just for debug
}
foreach ($groups in $KnownGoodProfileList) {
<command called that actually performs this on a platform but removed for privacy>
Write-Output "$(Get-Date) - Adding - $($groups.Group) - to - $($groups.Skill)" #just for debug
}
```

What I want to be able to do is to go through each group and remove all the skills and then add them on - which is where I am stuck.
So something along the lines of:

```
Remove all skills from Group 1 on Profiles2Cleanse list
Add all skill from Group 1 on KnownGoodProfileList
Remove all skills from Group 2 on Profiles2Cleanse list
Add all skill from Group 2 on KnownGoodProfileList
....
Remove all skills from Group 15 on Profiles2Cleanse list
Add all skill from Group 15 on KnownGoodProfileList
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `Compare-Object` to find differences and equalities between lists.

```
# The main list that is being updated
$master = Import-Csv master.csv

# Groups and Skills combinations that need to be removed from master.csv
$remove = Import-Csv remove.csv

# Groups and Skills combinations that need to be added to master.csv
$add = Import-Csv add.csv

# Remove unwanted groups/skills
# Finds only unique items from master list when compared to removed list
$master = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $master -DifferenceObject $remove -Property Group,Skill |
    where SideIndicator -eq '<=' |
        Select Group,Skill

# Add new groups/skills
# Finds all items from master and add lists (no duplicates)
$master = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $master -DifferenceObject $add -Property Group,Skill -IncludeEqual |
    Select Group,Skill

# Update master.csv
$master | Export-Csv master.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - I actually solved the issue in a similar fashion, where in both my separate files I added another column for the function of add/remove, then combined both csv's into one list, exported (because why not) then imported again but ordered by group asc, and action desc.  Then my normal for each followed by if statement.

Your way is definitely more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Much the same as the above poster I decided to take a similar approach to combine the lists with an extra field to denote the action.

```
#combine the CSVs into one list
$csv1 = Import-Csv $filePathRemove
$csv2 = Import-Csv $filePathAdd
$csv1 += $csv2
#export it because why not
$csv1 | Export-Csv $ExportCombined -NoTypeInformation
#import it again but sorted so it will remove skills and then add skills
$Profiles2Cleanse = Import-Csv $ExportCombined | sort @{expression='group';descending=$false}, action -Descending
foreach ($group in $Profiles2Cleanse){
    if($group.action -eq "remove") {
        Write-Output "$(Get-Date) - Removing - $($group.Group) - $($group.Skill)"
    }
    if($group.action -eq "add") {
        Write-Output "$(Get-Date) - Adding - $($group.Group) - to - $($group.Skill)"
    }
}
```